# Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome cant open anything (not even terminal)

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, desktop-environment

right now I run Gnome on my Linux server. I have 1 program open and thats VirtualBox with a lot of VM's, apart from that I cant open anything. I cant open the settings app, or terminal etc. The VM is working very smooth and also inside Virtualbox everything works fine.
EDIT: I am connected with Teamviewer, its also working

So why cant I open anything apart from VirtualBox?
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Can you ssh in?  Maybe get an error?

Comment: I can ssh in without any problem

Comment: Watch the logs, perhaps you can see what is going on when you try to launch processes.

Comment: Firefox or chrome dont produce logs and terminal also dont i guess

Comment: Typically processes launched from the graphical loginsend their output to a log like ~/.xsession-errors.